# Why there is additional space for a textfield?

Tags: jasper-reports

Why when i check on report the stretch with overflow property the textfield adds an extra space?

i have this configuration on it:

> the textfield has a height = 12 px
>   the width is the same of the page (572 px)
>   the font size = 10 px

In his image each line is a field, and doesn't contains line breaks except line 4,jasper adds one spaces after line 1 and 3 and additional for line 4. Here is the problem:

[image]

I compile my reports on windows and doesn't happen when i generate the report on windows, but this occurs on linux

Comment: You should add the sample to reproduce and the screenshot

Comment: One guess: Your data contains a line break.

Comment: hi ,thanks. the data doesn't contains line break. Its curious, maybe the string's lenght is related.
this image is ok:

https://imageshack.com/i/eym5Ddfjj

but this shows the problem:

https://imageshack.com/i/f03FCqNBp

Answer (score 0):

the solution which worked for me.

> 1. Create a new jasperfonts jar from ireport,
> 2. Add a spring.jar file and
> 3. Set the fonts to Arial
> 4. Make sure it runs ok in AIX.

Comment: @IsaacGSivaa - Why would they do that? If this is the answer (as it seems to be) then it should be posted as such.

Comment: This is the answer, though not very detailed.

Comment: hi, basically the problem was in the jars and fonts. Change the arial font and set it as default prevents the extra spaces in AIX and windows (less frequent)